Question regarding an implementation of OLS subset selection
On this website I found a Python implementation of Best Subset Selection, Forward Stepwise Selection etc. for choosing a set of predictors in an ordinary linear regression. It is supposed to be a supplement to the ISLP book by James, Witten, Hastie and Tibshirani.
The function fitting a single model and also calculating the corresponding RSS is given by
def processSubset(feature_set):
    # Fit model on feature_set and calculate RSS
    model = sm.OLS(y,X[list(feature_set)])
    regr = model.fit()
    RSS = ((regr.predict(X[list(feature_set)]) - y) ** 2).sum()
    return {"model":regr, "RSS":RSS}

and the function implementing one step in Forward Stepwise Selection
def forward(predictors):

# Pull out predictors we still need to process
remaining_predictors = [p for p in X.columns if p not in predictors]

tic = time.time()

results = []

for p in remaining_predictors:
    results.append(processSubset(predictors+[p]))

# Wrap everything up in a nice dataframe
models = pd.DataFrame(results)

# Choose the model with the highest RSS
best_model = models.loc[models['RSS'].argmin()]

toc = time.time()
print("Processed ", models.shape[0], "models on", len(predictors)+1, "predictors in", (toc-tic), "seconds.")

# Return the best model, along with some other useful information about the model
return best_model

It seems to me that this cannot be correct, since the intercept by default is not included in the regression? It is rather treated as a feature itself, so running this on some simulated data leads to the intercept being included at some step where it is the biggest improvement. Am I missing something? Shouldn't the line creating the model rather be something like
model = sm.OLS(y,sm.add_constant(X[feature_set]))

Thanks in advance!

Technically it isn't wrong to not include the intercept by default. Arguably in many applications one may want to force it into the model, but nothing in the theory and motivation of the approach enforces this.

But are these not completely different procedures? a) Having the "zero model" as just including the intercept and then adding variables step by step and b) Having the "zero model" as literally $0$ and then adding variables step by step, treating the intercept as a variable. It seems to be that the a) is what they are describing in the book and also be the thing that makes more sense, since we usually want to include an intercept in OLS.

They are not completely different, as technically the intercept can be treated as just another variable. I'd agree with you that normally we'd want to start with the intercept, but it is not in any well defined sense technically wrong not to do this.

Gotcha, thanks! Let me rephrase the question: If the goal of the authors of the code above was to implement the Forward Stepwise Selection algorithm as in the ISLP book, then is the code wrong since the intercept is not included by default?

Sorry, I don't have the time for looking up the book for this.
